# how do I replace = with ==, but ignore the equal in >= or <= using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

In a string like a=b I need to replace the equal with == (a==b). However I don't want to replace the equal in a<=b or a>=b.

I see regex has "(?!expr) Not followed by expr." but not "Not preceded by expr". I'm doing this in JavaScript.

Comment: Don't forget `+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` `&=` `|=` `^=` `!=` `~=` `!==` `===` etc etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't support the lookbehinds that are needed to make this work easily. However, you can simulate them:

```
.replace(/([^<>])=([^=])/g,"$1==$2")
```

Note that this won't replace any `=` that are at the start or end of the string, but given the context I don't think this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want Negative Lookbehind.

```
(?<!a)b
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Ah, I see the javascript specifics make this not work.  You might want to add the Javascript tag to your question to make that more clear.